# How to parse the result type containing managed metadata

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, search-results

I am using SharePoint 2013 search and getting the list items. The result contains managed metadata which is of format

> owstaxidmetadatagsallinfo: L0|#{Guid}|{Text};L0|#{Guid}|{Text}

If I use my custom column name which is a managed property I get the entire hierarcy (like GP0, GTSet ..)

Is there any API to directly convert this data into more readable format or is string manipulation the only way?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Automatically created managed properties in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136(v=office.15).aspx):

> **Data format for Managed Metadata.**   To query for items tagged with a Managed Metadata field, you have to use the Unique Identifier for
>   each label. You can find the Unique Identifier for each term in a term
>   set in the Term Store Management Tool, on the GENERAL tab. In
>   addition, the data format that is used in the query has to specify
>   from which level in the term set the query should apply. This
>   specification is set by adding one of the following prefixes to the
>   Unique Identifier:
>
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a term: `GP0|#`
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a child of term: `GPP|#`
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a term from a term set:    `GTSet|#`

Based on the provided information, the following example demonstrates how to parse search result for managed metadata field:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SharePoint.Client.Search.Results
{
    public class TaxonomySearchResultValue
    {
        public TaxonomySearchResultValue()
        {
            TermValues = new List<TermValue>();
            TermSetGuids = new List<Guid>();
        }

        public static TaxonomySearchResultValue Parse(string value)
        {
            var taxVal = new TaxonomySearchResultValue();
            var taxParts = value.Split(';');
            foreach (var taxPart in taxParts)
            {
                if (taxPart.StartsWith("GP0|#")) //Term?
                {
                    var termGuid = new Guid(taxPart.Replace("GP0|#", ""));
                    taxVal.TermValues.Add(new TermValue() { TermGuid = termGuid});
                }
                else if (taxPart.StartsWith("GTSet|#")) //Term Set?
                {
                    taxVal.TermSetGuids.Add(new Guid(taxPart.Replace("GTSet|#", "")));
                }
                else if (taxPart.StartsWith("L0|#")) //Term with label?
                {
                    var termParts = taxPart.Replace("L0|#0", "").Split('|');
                    var termGuid = new Guid(termParts[0]);
                    var termLabel = termParts[1];
                    var termVal = taxVal.TermValues.FirstOrDefault(ti => ti.TermGuid == termGuid);
                    if (termVal == null)
                        taxVal.TermValues.Add(new TermValue() {TermGuid = termGuid, Label = termLabel});
                    else
                        termVal.Label = termLabel;

                }
            }
            return taxVal;
        }

        public IList<TermValue> TermValues { get; set; }

        public IList<Guid> TermSetGuids { get; set; }


    }

    public class TermValue
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }

        public Guid TermGuid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var taxValue = "L0|#09d72d96c-407f-4e45-b2e6-9361faf5808a|Office;L0|#0ac96f075-b7d2-4e90-8dc2-da8875f395fc|Home";
var taxInfo = TaxonomySearchResultValue.Parse(taxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`TaxonomyFieldValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee577520.aspx) for this.

Like:

```
var taxCollection = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection("wss Id;#Label|Guid");

foreach(TaxonomyFieldValue value in taxCollection){
   var label = value.Label;
}
```

Comment: Wrong format. This will not work.