# SharePoint 2013 search result taxonomyfieldvalue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, managed-metadata, taxonomy

Unfortunately a SharePoint 2013 search result returns something which is not compatible with a TaxonomyFieldValue constructor.

If you pass a search result to a TaxonomyFieldValue ctor you will get the following error message: The given value for a taxonomy field was not formatted in the required ;#| format.

What I do get from a keyword query looks like that:

```
GP0|#d86df779-4fcc-45b0-a96e-8caaa84b4b1c;L0|#0d86df779-4fcc-45b0-a96e-8caaa84b4b1c|MyTermLabel;GTSet|#4b6fe410-c992-43c9-8149-80851a5b93b0
```

The last guid is the termset ID
The middle guid is the term's ID (label is "MyTermLabel").
I did not yet figure out what the first ID is. It is neither the Group nor the TermStore nor a reference to the taxonomy hidden list. I'm still in the dark on this one.

**Before I come up with something crazy to extract terms from this search result string - is there any built-in functionality?**

**Update:** There is some information on the syntax here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136(v=office.15).aspx But this describes search query options rather than "why is my result looking the way it is".

**Update:** Stumbled across this thread on SE [How to parse the result type containing managed metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72718/how-to-parse-the-result-type-containing-managed-metadata). The suggestion is to use the search result value with the TaxonomyFieldValue*Collection* ctor(). This is simply *wrong*! As with the TaxonomyFieldValue ctor() this is **NOT** working! Even if you strip away all the GP0 and GTSet fragments.

Answered my own question - moved the sample code to a separate answer posting to be able to put a green checkmark on it - for others to see there's a possible solution inside.

Comment: Cool stuff, thanks for posting your helper class. I think that there is something built-in, maybe its internal and you have to use reflection for that. Did you look for something related?

Comment: I did some digging with ILSpy but I didn't find anything useful. There should be some JavaScript logic for display template rendering somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I couldn't find any built-in functionality. I came up with a helper class. It is working very well so far. As far as my tests go I couldn't find any issues regarding localization or anything else.

```
namespace MyCompany.Common.SharePoint.Ecm.Taxonomy
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    // See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128965/sharepoint-2013-search-result-taxonomyfieldvalue
    public sealed class TaxonomySearchResultValue
    {
        private readonly string _searchResultValue;
        private readonly Dictionary<Guid, string> _terms;

        public TaxonomySearchResultValue(string searchResultString)
        {
            _searchResultValue = searchResultString;
            _terms = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();

            BuildTermsDictionary();
        }

        public Dictionary<Guid, string> Terms
        {
            get
            {
                return _terms;
            }
        }

        private void BuildTermsDictionary()
        {
            // EXAMPLE Input:
            // "GP0|#422f9d65-5b31-4334-a281-16e27b3d5dbd;L0|#0422f9d65-5b31-4334-a281-16e27b3d5dbd|Werkstudententätigkeit;GTSet|#2142cc53-6677-435f-a8ec-f923d6dfec9f;GP0|#a92202ba-92d4-4831-9003-0deaedf0feb7;L0|#0a92202ba-92d4-4831-9003-0deaedf0feb7|Praktikum;GP0|#76a22c22-a3fd-4efc-85d2-cc0dcdb12bf1;L0|#076a22c22-a3fd-4efc-85d2-cc0dcdb12bf1|Duales Studium";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchResultValue)) return;

            string[] split = _searchResultValue.Split(';');

            foreach (string tuple in split)
            {
                if (tuple.StartsWith("L0|")) // NOTE: No clue what L0| even means - appears to be a term.
                {
                    string[] frags = tuple.Split('|');
                    if (frags.Length == 3)
                    {
                        string id = frags[1];
                        Guid termId = new Guid(id.Substring(id.Length - 36, 36)); // Guid is 32bit + 4 dashes

                        _terms.Add(termId, frags[2]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting object instance contains a property "Terms" which is simply a `Dictionary<Guid, string>` where `Guid is the term's id` and `string is the term's label`.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue.  When reviewing the crawled properties, I saw 2 crawled properties were created but only the managed property for the problem result was generated.   I manually created the managed property mapped to the 2nd crawled property, added to my display template, and ran a full crawl so now only label displays in result.

The two crawled properties had the same suffix which came through via a search of the suffix in the crawled property administration.

Example:

- **ows_taxId_AlertVoice** (this is the one with automatically created managed property)
- **ows_AlertVoice** (this is the one which generated just the label when I manually created managed property).

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned in the question, [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136(v=office.15).aspx) contains the following explanation about the format of search result value for managed metadata field:

> **Data format for Managed Metadata.**
>   To query for items tagged with a Managed Metadata field, you have to use the >Unique Identifier for
>   each label. You can find the Unique Identifier for each term in a term
>   set in the Term Store Management Tool, on the GENERAL tab. In
>   addition, the data format that is used in the query has to specify
>   from which level in the term set the query should apply. This
>   specification is set by adding one of the following prefixes to the
>   Unique Identifier:
>
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a term: `GP0|#`
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a child of term: `GPP|#`
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a term from a term set:    `GTSet|#`

Having said that, i've come up with the following solution to parse search result value for *managed metadata* field:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SharePoint.Client.Search.Results
{
    public class TaxonomySearchResultValue
    {
        public TaxonomySearchResultValue()
        {
            TermValues = new List<TermValue>();
            TermSetGuids = new List<Guid>();
        }

        public static TaxonomySearchResultValue Parse(string value)
        {
            var taxVal = new TaxonomySearchResultValue();
            var taxParts = value.Split(';');
            foreach (var taxPart in taxParts)
            {
                if (taxPart.StartsWith("GP0|#")) //Term?
                {
                    var termGuid = new Guid(taxPart.Replace("GP0|#", ""));
                    taxVal.TermValues.Add(new TermValue() { TermGuid = termGuid});
                }
                else if (taxPart.StartsWith("GTSet|#")) //Term Set?
                {
                    taxVal.TermSetGuids.Add(new Guid(taxPart.Replace("GTSet|#", "")));
                }
                else if (taxPart.StartsWith("L0|#")) //Term with label?
                {
                    var termParts = taxPart.Replace("L0|#0", "").Split('|');
                    var termGuid = new Guid(termParts[0]);
                    var termLabel = termParts[1];
                    var termVal = taxVal.TermValues.FirstOrDefault(ti => ti.TermGuid == termGuid);
                    if (termVal == null)
                        taxVal.TermValues.Add(new TermValue() {TermGuid = termGuid, Label = termLabel});
                    else
                        termVal.Label = termLabel;

                }
            }
            return taxVal;
        }

        public IList<TermValue> TermValues { get; set; }

        public IList<Guid> TermSetGuids { get; set; }


    }

    public class TermValue
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }

        public Guid TermGuid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var taxValue = "L0|#09d72d96c-407f-4e45-b2e6-9361faf5808a|Office;L0|#0ac96f075-b7d2-4e90-8dc2-da8875f395fc|Home";
var taxInfo = TaxonomySearchResultValue.Parse(taxValue);
Console.WriteLine(taxInfo.TermValues[0].Label);  //print first term label
```